# Typescript map Array of objects to one merged object type type declaration

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I have an array of objects like this

```
const barDependency = {
  defaults: {
    size: {
      bar: {
        foo: 12,
        bar: {
          default: 12,
          active: 12
        }
      }
    },
    color: {}
  }
}
```

and an original object like this:

```
const theme = {
   size: {
     m: '12px'
   }
}
```

The function that should merge both should take everything thats within `barDependency.defaults.size` and put it within `theme.size.components`
The logic of this function is quite easy but TS can't infer the output so I decided to declare the ReturnType myself with TS [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like the following:

```
const stitchTheme = <
  T extends RawTheme,
  D extends ThemeDependency[] = ThemeDependency[],
  A extends number = number
>(
  dependencies: D,
  options?: StitchThemeOptions
): T & {
  size: T['size'] & {
    components?: {
      [Key in KeysOfUnion<
        D[A]['defaults']['size']
      >]: D[A]['defaults']['size'][Key]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I can't access the value of given object by its index in array even with an generic pointing to the same number. The value of `size.components.bar` will be `unknown`.
Is there any way to resolve this properly?

KeysOfUnion Type for reference `type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never`

Answer (score 1):

After some research I came across this article: https://dev.to/lucianbc/union-type-merging-in-typescript-9al

In which will be explained how to achieve merging object unions by using with custom utillity types:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never
type PickType<T, K extends AllKeys<T>> = T extends { [k in K]: any }
  ? T[K]
  : undefined
type PickTypeOf<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = K extends AllKeys<T>
  ? PickType<T, K>
  : never
type Merge<T extends object> = {
  [k in AllKeys<T>]: PickTypeOf<T, k>
}
```